# Jupyter Notebook error during saving

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Everything used to work fine but now every time I try saving any file in Jupyter Notebook, I get the following error.

```
URIError: URIMalformed
```

Also the following is shown in the title bar.

```
Last Checkpoint: 09/02/2016 Autosave Failed!
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution for the Lastpass users:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1966

adding "localhost" to My Vault -> Account Settings -> Neverl URLS -> "Never Add Site"

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is a much nicer solution!

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this same error as well.  I ended up tracing it down to the LastPass extension in Chrome.  I disabled the extension, and I was able to save again.

[lastpass] [jupyter]

Comment: Maybe it's a combination of lastpass and %

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue and tracked it back to the character `%`.

I'm using it in the line `%matplotlib auto`.

I don't even have to run the line of code. Just having it in my text prompts the error. If I remove the character, then I can save again.

Remove any `%` and see if you can then save.

Comment: For me, I tried removing modulos, and it worked at first but then didn't.  I think it's lastpass as wolfins said.  I switched to opera (with no lastpass) from chrome (with lastpass) and it's working now, even with %

Comment: Per other suggestions, I disabled my LastPass extension in Chrome and it works fine, even if `%` is present. Seems to be a shifty bug.

Comment: I logged out of my last pass extension in chrome and removed all `%` in the files and it worked for me. Definitely a shifty bug!

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Scott's answer above. I also got the exact same error messages you got using Python 3.5.1. I fixed the issue by getting rid of any `%` characters in my code per Scott's answer from yesterday. I needed the `%` for the modulo operator. I just imported `operator.mod()` instead.

Aside: This is such a quirky bug!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to globally disabling the LastPass extension in Chrome, I was able to get things working by running the notebook in a Chrome incognito window.

Additionally, this issue only seems to affect Chrome. Even with LastPass enabled in Firefox, I've been able to save the notebooks without the urierror.

Not using '%' in Jupyter Notebooks doesn't seem like a solution, since the magics all start with % and even having % in a print statement causes the error.