# Why does Jupyter notebook fail to authenticate WebSocket connection?

Tags: python, websocket, jupyter-notebook

I am creating a fresh Python 3 virtual environment with a Jupyter notebook server using the following commands:

```
virtualenv env -p python3
. env/bin/activate
pip install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

These all run successfully. But when I try to create a new notebook, I get a WebSocket authentication error and am unable to create the notebook. The client says

> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

Here is the log from the Jupyter notebook server:

```
[I 22:50:23.085 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 22:50:23.110 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tmp
[I 22:50:23.110 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 22:50:23.110 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/?token=b4d69926e308334a4ca121d3ceaa0dfa9f1ba93312770f88
[I 22:50:23.110 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 22:50:36.778 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from 127.0.0.1
[I 22:52:01.083 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[W 22:52:06.372 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20161215225022 (127.0.0.1) 38.39ms referer=http://localhost:8889/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 22:52:06.855 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 7b5db30f-e2b2-48dc-9ec8-2aa9bd63b604
[W 22:52:07.130 NotebookApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 22:52:07.140 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/7b5db30f-e2b2-48dc-9ec8-2aa9bd63b604/channels?session_id=277CA36E71FA431C922EE9F8AEFF6261 (127.0.0.1) 14.42ms referer=None
[W 22:52:08.435 NotebookApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 22:52:08.446 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/7b5db30f-e2b2-48dc-9ec8-2aa9bd63b604/channels?session_id=277CA36E71FA431C922EE9F8AEFF6261 (127.0.0.1) 16.36ms referer=None
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
[W 22:52:10.619 NotebookApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 22:52:10.622 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/7b5db30f-e2b2-48dc-9ec8-2aa9bd63b604/channels?session_id=277CA36E71FA431C922EE9F8AEFF6261 (127.0.0.1) 10.53ms referer=None
[W 22:52:14.657 NotebookApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 22:52:14.666 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/7b5db30f-e2b2-48dc-9ec8-2aa9bd63b604/channels?session_id=277CA36E71FA431C922EE9F8AEFF6261 (127.0.0.1) 15.54ms referer=None
```

What does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

I am using Ubuntu 16.10, Python 3.5.2, and Jupyter 4.2.1.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this exact same error yesterday and it turned out it was caused by the lastpass chrome plugin. See this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095166/3536518) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the [Brave browser](https://brave.com/), but now I've switched to Firefox and it works.

Comment: Mac OS 10.14.6, the issue was 1blocker in Safari, just had to add the page to the whitelist and it works fine.